# Add more fix points to a Data Flow Diagram using Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm trying to replicate a Data Flow Diagram using Draw.io.

I'm using the oval basic shape but there are not enough fix points.

Is it possible to add more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fixed points by changing the style, as [per this example](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042498-how-to-add-remove-connection-points-how-to-connect-anywhere-on-a-shape-).

Comment: Mentioned link is redirecting to 'page not found'

Comment: This answer helped me find a solution! <3 I've created [**a separate answer with full steps to get it done**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142125/19610), should the link in this answer ever rot (again).

Answer (score 5):

[The accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44956/19610) links to [the right documentation](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042498-how-to-add-remove-connection-points-how-to-connect-anywhere-on-a-shape-) but it seems helpful to have a fully detailed answer on Stack Exchange, including a copy/pasteable example.

Here's the steps:

1. Right click your shape
2. Pick "Edit Style" from the context menu

   [image: right click menu]
3. Add a key `points` with a value with an array of coordinates (values between 0 and 1 for place on the side of a shape), e.g. `points=[ [0.0, 0.0],  [0.0, 0.5], [0.0, 1.0], etc ]`

   [image: add style to shape]
4. Click apply and you're done.

Here's a particularly useful example:

**10 anchor points per side (incl. corners):**

```
points=[[0,0],[0,0.1],[0,0.2],[0,0.3],[0,0.4],[0,0.5],[0,0.6],[0,0.7],[0,0.8],[0,0.9],[0,1],[0.1,0],[0.2,0],[0.3,0],[0.4,0],[0.5,0],[0.6,0],[0.7,0],[0.8,0],[0.9,0],[1,0],[1,0.1],[1,0.2],[1,0.3],[1,0.4],[1,0.5],[1,0.6],[1,0.7],[1,0.8],[1,0.9],[0.1,1],[0.2,1],[0.3,1],[0.4,1],[0.5,1],[0.6,1],[0.7,1],[0.8,1],[0.9,1],[1,1]]
```

Or, the full style for a default white rectangular box:

```
rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;points=[[0,0],[0,0.1],[0,0.2],[0,0.3],[0,0.4],[0,0.5],[0,0.6],[0,0.7],[0,0.8],[0,0.9],[0,1],[0.1,0],[0.2,0],[0.3,0],[0.4,0],[0.5,0],[0.6,0],[0.7,0],[0.8,0],[0.9,0],[1,0],[1,0.1],[1,0.2],[1,0.3],[1,0.4],[1,0.5],[1,0.6],[1,0.7],[1,0.8],[1,0.9],[0.1,1],[0.2,1],[0.3,1],[0.4,1],[0.5,1],[0.6,1],[0.7,1],[0.8,1],[0.9,1],[1,1]]
```

Looks like this:

[image: end result]

---

**Also useful for standard boxes, example with 5 points on left/right, and 10 on top/bottom:**

```
points=[[0,0],[0,0.25],[0,0.5],[0,0.75],[0,1],[0.1,0],[0.2,0],[0.3,0],[0.4,0],[0.5,0],[0.6,0],[0.7,0],[0.8,0],[0.9,0],[1,0],[1,0.25],[1,0.5],[1,0.75],[0.1,1],[0.2,1],[0.3,1],[0.4,1],[0.5,1],[0.6,1],[0.7,1],[0.8,1],[0.9,1],[1,1]]
```

Comment: Note that the points are moved to its nearest outer Edge for Example when your shape is a 5x5 Rectangle and you set a point to [0.5,0,5] it will be rendered like [1.0,0.5]

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps someone, I wrote a python script to generate the string for evenly spaced points on a rect

https://gist.github.com/gmkado/ab12ea0d0b5dbf589ec39b1b221f51d5

EDIT:

I'm guessing the downvotes are due to not explaining this well.  If you run the code from that script as a python script it will print out the "points" array that you can then copy-paste into the drawio style.  Here's a link to run it in the browser so you don't even need python locally:
https://trinket.io/python3/ae199c59c1

Modify this section:

```
# SET THESE TO THE NUMBER OF POINTS YOU NEED
top = 0
left = 0
right = 13
bottom = 0
```

Running this will print out:

```
points=[[1.00, 0.00],[1.00, 0.08],[1.00, 0.17],[1.00, 0.25],[1.00, 0.33],[1.00, 0.42],[1.00, 0.50],[1.00, 0.58],[1.00, 0.67],[1.00, 0.75],[1.00, 0.83],[1.00, 0.92],[1.00, 1.00]]
```

Then copy-paste:

[image]

And voila:

[image]

Comment: This is a very helpful answer.Thanks for sharing the code!

Comment: A slightly modified version of the code: https://gist.github.com/gmkado/ab12ea0d0b5dbf589ec39b1b221f51d5#gistcomment-3718030

Answer (score 0):

Select the element you want to change. Click on edit style and add the parameter points after a semicolon:

```
points=[[0,0], [1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
```

The example above will create 4 fixpoint in each corner. So you need list of lists `[[x_i,y_i]]` with elements between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

With the intention to make it clearer and as specified in the documentation the connection/anchor point can be places even inside the shape by using the third parameter (1 = tight the point to the edge, 0 = place it anywhere inside the shape)
Negative numbers default to 0 and bigger than 1 default to 1

Activation for Snappoints makes easier to tie connectors to anchors.

```
points=[[0.25,0.5,0],[0.75,0.5,0]]
```